# How to define dynamic log file names in log configuration file in Python?

Tags: logging, python-2.7, testcase

I am writing unit testcase in python. I want to create custom logging in python. When I run a testcase, I want two new files to be created, one saves info logs and the other saves debug logs. I am able to achieve this in config file. But my files names should be dynamic with a time stamp. How I can able to achieve this?

For example if testcase.py is run, log-12-2-2013_23:30:31.log and debug_log-12-2-2013_23:30:31.log

Also for each run, new files to be created.

Thanks,

Comment: Easier to dump it into a single log file and filter using a separate tool. I generally use perl, but you may find python easier.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try using logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html